# Linux stops booting after eth0 link up. How to make it show more log?

Tags: linux, openwrt

I compiled the latest OpenWRT with Linux kernel 4.4.7 and flashed it into a Netgear WNDR3700v2. Here's the boot log from serial port.

```
U-Boot 1.1.4 (Jan 15 2015 - 11:30:07)

AP96 (AR7161 rev 2) U-Boot
DRAM:  128 MB
Flash: Macronix MX25L12835E (16 MB)
Using default environment

Clocks: CPU:680MHz, DDR:340MHz, AHB:170MHz, Ref:40MHz
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   ag7100_enet_initialize...
No valid address in Flash. Using fixed MAC Address
No valid address in Flash. Using fixed MAC Address
GMAC: cfg1 0xf cfg2 0x7014
eth0: 00:03:7f:09:0b:ad
eth0 up
GMAC: cfg1 0xf cfg2 0x7014
eth1: 00:03:7f:09:0b:ad
eth1 up
eth0, eth1
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
### SQUASHFS loading 'image/uImage' to 0x80800000
### SQUASHFS load complete: 1376256 bytes loaded to 0x80800000
## Booting image at 80800000 ...
   Image Name:   MIPS OpenWrt Linux-4.4.7
   Created:      2016-04-17  22:20:11 UTC
   Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (lzma compressed)
   Data Size:    1330577 Bytes =  1.3 MB
   Load Address: 80060000
   Entry Point:  80060000
   Verifying Checksum at 0x80800040 ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.7 (wesley@localhost) (gcc version 5.3.0 (OpenWrt GCC 5.3.0 r49195) ) #3 Mon Apr 18 06:37:58 UTC 2016
[    0.000000] bootconsole [early0] enabled
[    0.000000] CPU0 revision is: 00019374 (MIPS 24Kc)
[    0.000000] SoC: Atheros AR7161 rev 2
[    0.000000] Determined physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  memory: 08000000 @ 00000000 (usable)
[    0.000000] Initrd not found or empty - disabling initrd
[    0.000000] No valid device tree found, continuing without
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000007ffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000007ffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000007ffffff]
[    0.000000] Primary instruction cache 64kB, VIPT, 4-way, linesize 32 bytes.
[    0.000000] Primary data cache 32kB, 4-way, VIPT, cache aliases, linesize 32 bytes
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
[    0.000000] Kernel command line:  board=WNDR3700 mtdparts=spi0.0:320k(u-boot)ro,128k(u-boot-env)ro,15872k(firmware),64k(art)ro console=ttyS0,115200 rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Writing ErrCtl register=00000000
[    0.000000] Readback ErrCtl register=00000000
[    0.000000] Memory: 125204K/131072K available (2932K kernel code, 152K rwdata, 744K rodata, 260K init, 200K bss, 5868K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:51
[    0.000000] Clocks: CPU:680.000MHz, DDR:340.000MHz, AHB:170.000MHz, Ref:40.000MHz
[    0.000000] clocksource: MIPS: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 5621354254 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 32 bits at 340MHz, resolution 2ns, wraps every 6316128254ns
[    0.007780] Calibrating delay loop... 452.19 BogoMIPS (lpj=2260992)
[    0.070505] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.075225] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.081837] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.090915] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.101352] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.106751] MIPS: machine is NETGEAR WNDR3700/WNDR3800/WNDRMAC
[    2.752903] registering PCI controller with io_map_base unset
[    2.765999] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    2.770151] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x10000000-0x16ffffff]
[    2.777007] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000]
[    2.782574] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x0]
[    2.789346] pci_bus 0000:00: No busn resource found for root bus, will use [bus 00-ff]
[    2.797331] pci 0000:00:11.0: fixup device configuration
[    2.804098] pci 0000:00:12.0: fixup device configuration
[    2.810875] pci 0000:00:11.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x10000000-0x1000ffff]
[    2.817657] pci 0000:00:12.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x10010000-0x1001ffff]
[    2.824462] pci 0000:00:11.0: using irq 40 for pin 1
[    2.829416] pci 0000:00:12.0: using irq 41 for pin 1
[    2.835081] clocksource: Switched to clocksource MIPS
[    2.841158] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    2.846252] TCP established hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.853221] TCP bind hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.859613] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 1024)
[    2.866051] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.871887] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.878381] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    2.883579] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    2.902548] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    2.908438] jffs2: version 2.2 (NAND) (SUMMARY) (LZMA) (RTIME) (CMODE_PRIORITY) (c) 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    2.920214] io scheduler noop registered
[    2.924143] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    2.929696] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    2.936431] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    2.960048] serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x18020000 (irq = 11, base_baud = 10625000) is a 16550A
[    2.968754] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.968754] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.975715] bootconsole [early0] disabled
[    2.975715] bootconsole [early0] disabled
[    2.986372] m25p80 spi0.0: found mx25l12805d, expected m25p80
[    2.992122] m25p80 spi0.0: mx25l12805d (16384 Kbytes)
[    2.997236] 4 cmdlinepart partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
[    3.003137] Creating 4 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
[    3.007942] 0x000000000000-0x000000050000 : "u-boot"
[    3.014619] 0x000000050000-0x000000070000 : "u-boot-env"
[    3.021309] 0x000000070000-0x000000ff0000 : "firmware"
[    3.040253] 2 netgear-fw partitions found on MTD device firmware
[    3.046298] 0x000000070000-0x0000001b6440 : "kernel"
[    3.052382] 0x0000001b6440-0x000000ff0000 : "rootfs"
[    3.058685] mtd: device 4 (rootfs) set to be root filesystem
[    3.064391] 1 squashfs-split partitions found on MTD device rootfs
[    3.070612] 0x000000410000-0x000000ff0000 : "rootfs_data"
[    3.077349] 0x000000ff0000-0x000001000000 : "art"
[    3.084250] Realtek RTL8366S ethernet switch driver version 0.2.2
[    3.090429] rtl8366s rtl8366s: using GPIO pins 5 (SDA) and 7 (SCK)
[    3.096695] rtl8366s rtl8366s: RTL8366 ver. 1 chip found
[    3.142470] libphy: rtl8366s: probed
[    3.466770] eth0: Atheros AG71xx at 0xb9000000, irq 4, mode:RGMII
[    3.786924] ag71xx ag71xx.1: connected to PHY at rtl8366s:04 [uid=001cc960, driver=Generic PHY]
[    3.796246] eth1: Atheros AG71xx at 0xba000000, irq 5, mode:RGMII
[    3.804209] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    3.811932] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    3.816496] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[    3.829205] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    3.839848] VFS: Mounted root (squashfs filesystem) readonly on device 31:4.
[    3.847744] Freeing unused kernel memory: 260K (8041f000 - 80460000)
[    4.768274] init: Console is alive
[    4.771859] init: - watchdog -
[    5.751955] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    5.757566] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    5.762950] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    5.772288] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    5.780101] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    5.785453] ehci-platform ehci-platform: EHCI Host Controller
[    5.791230] ehci-platform ehci-platform: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    5.799247] ehci-platform ehci-platform: irq 3, io mem 0x1b000000
[    5.825113] ehci-platform ehci-platform: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    5.832136] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.836185] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    5.842660] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    5.850013] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    5.855357] ohci-platform ohci-platform: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    5.862157] ohci-platform ohci-platform: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    5.870155] ohci-platform ohci-platform: irq 14, io mem 0x1c000000
[    5.939900] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.943895] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    5.949443] init: - preinit -
[    6.475369] eth0: link up (1000Mbps/Full duplex)
```

It hangs here for a few seconds then reboots itself, over and over. What should I do to know what happened there, since the log provides no more than this?

By the way, it boots fine if I replace Linux kernel 4.4.7 with 4.1.20.

Comment: Is the [kernel command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) for both kernels identical?

Comment: @SamiLaine Yep.

Comment: Does both kernels are installed from repository, or compiled by you. Probably there is missing some module. You can try to enter to singleuser mode, and check it. Or boot some live cd and chroot to this system and check logs

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug log from bootargs to see more logs.
loglevel is the kernel bootargs, you can set the respective flag to display further logs.

loglevel=       All Kernel Messages with a loglevel smaller than the
                    console loglevel will be printed to the console. It can
                    also be changed with klogd or other programs. The
                    loglevels are defined as follows:

```
                0 (KERN_EMERG)          system is unusable
                1 (KERN_ALERT)          action must be taken immediately
                2 (KERN_CRIT)           critical conditions
                3 (KERN_ERR)            error conditions
                4 (KERN_WARNING)        warning conditions
                5 (KERN_NOTICE)         normal but significant condition
                6 (KERN_INFO)           informational
                7 (KERN_DEBUG)          debug-level messages
```